# Why does an EXR file light my scene differently than an HDR of the same file?

Tags: light, lighting, hdri

EDIT: I solved the issue. The creator contacted me and said he edited the file considerably. Mods: feel free to delete.

---

So I was provided with a scene from someone - It's a simple shaderball setup.

It came with an EXR file called `cayley_interior_2k.exr`. I quickly realized it's from HDRI Haven:

**Provided EXR:**

[image: Provided EXR]

**HDR Directly from HDRI Haven:**

[image: HDR from HDRI Haven]

They look pretty close to me, so I was surprised to find that if I swap out the provided EXR with the HDR I have locally, I get *drastically* different lighting.

**Scene with provided EXR:**

[image: Shaderball A]

**Scene with my own HDR:**

[image: Shaderball B]

You can see pretty clearly that the EXR contributes much more of a blue-ish cast to the scene despite visually looking almost identical.

Here are both files:

[HDR From HDRI Haven](https://www.dropbox.com/s/60b1n05str0sqve/from_hdri_haven.hdr?dl=0)

[EXR From Provided Scene](https://www.dropbox.com/s/api4x5e5y6pv9qt/from_provided_scene.exr?dl=0)

Here is the scene if you want to try and reproduce:

[image]

Really appreciate any kind of help at all!

Comment: I guess inspecting the scene might be necessary, do you mind adding it to your q?

Comment: I don't have permission to attach the exact scene I was given, but I will quickly create a scene that reproduces the same behavior and then add it.

Comment: @brockmann I just added a scene to the post. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Hello :). Checking the histogram - the EXR has shifted, and (normalized?) individual RGB channels. There is also some noticeable clipping in the Waveform display and overall lower exposure.

Comment: @JachymMichal Interesting. I did think that the image was edited a little bit, but the strong blue cast on the final result seemed a bit crazy for a slightly modified image. Do you think this is definitely why they look so different when used in a scene?

Comment: @JachymMichal Thanks sir. :) I actually just got in touch with the person who provided the scene to me and he said that he edited it to remove the overhead lights. So that explains things!

Comment: No problem :). Checking it a bit more - the EXR shows significantly clipped Red channel, that would explain the blue tint.